# What is the thing in square brackets that comes before a C# class declaration called?

Tags: c#

What is the `[something]` in

```
[something]
public class c1 {

}
```

called in C#? What does it do?

Comment: They are called Attributes.

Comment: Simply right click on it an select *Go to definition*

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is \[\] brackets in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968597/what-is-brackets-in-net)

Comment: Or a dupe of [Meaning of text between square brackets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771772/meaning-of-text-between-square-brackets). I don't think this is ambiguous so much as well duped, but that reduces to the same thing -- question closure -- so fair enough, I guess. ;^)

Comment: @Joe 'possible' duplicate is not 'is' duplicate and .net is not C#. ruffin The title of that post makes it nowhere near as discoverable through Google as this one. It should really say "Closed due to StackExchange bureaucracy".

Comment: This is a very helpful question for programmers who are not coming from a C# background!

Answer (score 38):

That's an [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: **Updated links** [Attributes (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/index) & [Extending Metadata Using Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/)

Answer (score 14):

This is known as an attribute application / usage.  It associates an instance of a given `Attribute` with a type.  These are user definitable items.  For example

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class ExampleAttribute : System.Attribute {
  public ExampleAttribute() { }
}
```

This is an attribute which can be applied on ever place an attribute is legal

```
// Assembly level
[assembly: Example]

// Class
[Example]
public class C1 {
  // Field
  [Example]
  public int m_field;

  // Method
  [Example]
  public void Test() { }
}
```

More locations are possible but hopefully this gets the general idea across.  You may also want to check out this tutorial

- [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Shouldn't the `:` go *after* `assembly`?

Answer (score 2):

Its called an Attribute.  A class that ends in "Attribute", and inherits from Attribute:

```
public class SomethingAttribute : Attribute {

}
```

If you are creating one, be sure to look up the [AttributeUsageAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute.aspx) class.

Comment: Note that ending the name of an attribute class with `Attribute` is a convention; it's not a requirement.

Comment: Absolutely correct.  Conventions are good to follow where possible.

Answer (score 2):

C# Attributes.  Please see this [documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/attributes/)