# Square brackets in a class

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meaning of text between square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771772/meaning-of-text-between-square-brackets)

The class I'm looking at looks like

```
public class SaveBundle
{
        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public SaveBundleHeader Header
        {
            get
            {
                return this.headerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.headerField = value;
            }
        }
}
```

I don't know why the [System.Xml.Serialisztion.Xml etc] exists or what it is called to research it further?

Can some one tell me the name of [] and what in this example it's purpose is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the attribute `XmlElement` being set on the property `Header`

You should be able to look it up as `XmlElementAttribute` on MSDN. Like [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx).

Comment: So, if I used that attribute on all of my properties/fields, could I actually use my object like an Xml object?

Comment: You can serialize your object to Xml even without the attributes. The attributes allow you to control _how_ it is encoded more precisely.

Answer (score 6):

It's an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), used to decorate things with accessible metadata. You can use [reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get at this data and do something with it. Many parts of the framework already do this, as with the example in the MSDN link for attributes marking a class `Serializable` - you could do custom serialization based on metadata but you don't always need to because 'auto-serialization' is already implemented based on this concept.

The square brackets are the syntax used to apply them, as demonstrated in your example.

Comment: Although clearly (by votes) the best answer as to what the square brackets mean, HenkHolterman's answer happened to explain something extra for me and my current project. So plus 1 but please don't be offended that I didn't mark as answer.

Comment: That's only fair, and one of the great benefits of this place: varied views on how to answer and, of course, the counsel of many. (:

Answer (score 2):

That's an attribute.

MSDN provides [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) all the info about attributes (what they are, what they mean, and so).

Answer (score 1):

In order to format your property when you serialize your type

Indicates that a public field or property represents an XML element when the XmlSerializer serializes or deserializes the object that contains it.